# Fill the NaN values with fillna not giving correct output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with columns **stud_id,stud_class,stud_mark**. some values in stud_mark as marked as **NaN**. My requirement is to fill the NaN values with average of marks obtained from each class. while doing so the NaN value is not changing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data=({'stud_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
'stud_class': ['1st', '1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd'],
 'stud_mark': [100, np.nan, 90, np.nan, 80]})
df=pd.DataFrame(data) 
print(df)
# Calculate the average mark for each class
average_mark = df.groupby('stud_class')['stud_mark'].mean()

# Fill the blank marks with the average mark for each class
df['stud_mark'] = df['stud_mark'].fillna(average_mark)

print(df)
```

output

```
stud_id stud_class  stud_mark
0        1        1st      100.0
1        2        1st        NaN
2        3        1st       90.0
3        4        2nd        NaN
4        5        2nd       80.0
```

Need some input on this to resolve.

Comment: i think you just have to do `df['stud_mark'] = df['stud_mark'].fillna(average_mark)` (fillna does not operate inplace)

Comment: @rhug123, i tried that also, it is not working

Comment: I think originally your previous statement was `average_mark = df.groupby('stud_class')['stud_mark'].transform('mean')`. If you do that, and then `df['stud_mark'] = df['stud_mark'].fillna(average_mark)` it should work.

Comment: yes its working now with transform(), but it doesnot work with mean() only??

Comment: Because of incorrect indexing. See the duplicate.